# Camera.Face.leftEye not existing

Tags: java, android, face-detection

I am trying to detect the left eye of my face in my camera app.
(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html)

I successfully detected a face and put a rectangle around it, but the component `Camera.Face.leftEye` is allways `null`, even though the face and the eye is clearly visible.

```
Rect r = getRectFromCamera(face.rect);
   paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
   canvas.drawRect(r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, paint);

   paint.setColor(Color.RED);

   if(face.leftEye != null) {
      canvas.drawCircle(r.left, r.top, 50,paint); //just some testing to see if it would be off canvas
      canvas.drawCircle(getXFromCamera(face.leftEye.x), getYFromCamera(face.leftEye.y), 50, paint);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the documentation

> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html#leftEye

leftEye, rightEye and mouth are optional fields, that are not supported on all devices. Furthermore, they are supported as a set, so if one of them works, all them work. Vice versa, no one works.

I tried this set on Asus Zenfone Selfie and Samsung S6 Edge Plus and they always return NULL.